# limits of sequences of topological rings

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $A$ such that $A$ is complete in the $I$-adic topology. Let $a \in I$. Then the sequence $y_n=1-a+a^2-a^3+\cdots+(-1)^n a^n$ converges in $A$. By definition of completeness, this means that there exists a unique element $x \in A$ such that 
$y_n - x \in I^n, \, \, \, \forall n$.

Question: Why does that imply that we can view the infinite series $1-a+a^2-a^3+\cdots$ as an element of $A$? In particular i encountered the argument that because $(y_n)$ converges, then 
$1-a+a^2-a^3+\cdots$ is the inverse of $1+a$, hence $1+a$ is a unit.

Reference: Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory proof of theorem 8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $1-a+a^2-a^3\dots$ is just suggestive shorthand for $x\in A$. Take a look at what it means in terms of limits (in the way we are accustomed to doing for sequences of real numbers.)

If you compute $y_n(1+a)=1+(-1)^{n+1}a^n$, then

$$
x(1+a)=\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n(1+a)=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1+(-1)^{n+1}a^n=1+\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^{n+1}a^n
$$

But since $a\in I$, the limit on the far RHS is $0$. (This is because $\pm a^n\in I^n$ for each $n$, and $\cap I^n=\{0\}$.)

Comment: +1 Very interesting, so the idea is that algebraic operations and limits interact as in the case of real numbers, that's what i was missing.

Comment: $\cap_n I^n = \{0\}$ is not used.

Comment: @Manos Yeah, that's the idea. Since the topology is compatible with the algebraic structure (just as with real numbers!) then you can draw these sorts of conclusions much in the same way.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg How does one determine that the last limit is $0$ without that condition?

Comment: One uses the *definition* of convergence and the $I$-adic topology. It shows that $\lim a_n = 0$ when $a_n \in I^n$. It is not used that $\cap_n I^n = \{0\}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Literally true, I suppose. I guess its the reader's preference on whether or not they want their limit to be unique.

Comment: No, please repeat the definitions (before teaching others).

Comment: And here the uniqueness of limits is not important at all. We don't need it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I guess the only fair interpretation of your condescending remark is that you misunderstood me. I did not dispute that 0 was a limit: I just used the zero intersection to eliminate doubt that the zero can be inserted for the limit in the $x(1+a)=1+0$ computation. So, the question is that if limits are not unique, how do you resolve for a student that $x(1+a)=1+0=1+t$ for some $t\neq 0$? It seems like avoiding using the intersection in the interest of generality sacrifices this convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This is just notation. By definition, in a topological group, $a_0+a_1+\dotsc$ denotes a limit of the sequence $(a_0+\dotsc+a_n)_{n \geq 0}$, as soon as it exists.

If we work in a topological ring with $I$-adic topology and if $a \in I$, then $(1-a)(1+a+a^2+\dotsc)$ is the limit of $(1-a)(1+a+a^2+\dotsc+a^n)=1-a^{n+1}$, which is $1$ by definition of the $I$-adic topology.

Comment: Ok, then why do we have that $x(1+a) = 1$ where $x$ is the limit?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "a limit".